# Excel: Conditional “Blanking” of Cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I really don’t use excel often and I am trying to create an amortization schedule that removes the displaying of irrelevant values.

[image]

Since values in column G eventually become less than 0, any values below the highlighted row are irrelevant. I’ve tried so many combinations of logic using ISERROR’s, ISBLANKS, IF’s, and OR’s never getting what I’d expect.

The current formula for column G:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show some of the formulas you've tried to help provide more clarity for your inquiry.  This could be as simple as `=if(E264>G263,0,G263-E264)`, but I need more understanding of what you've tried and the expected outcome (across your sheet).

Comment: @Cyril please see edit. It _almost_ works in the sense that one blank entry is created but it needs to descend the rest of the sheet. Additionally, it would be preferable if in this scenario G264 is blank since its negative

Comment: *What* is the "it" that almost worked? A macro? a formula? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56241911/edit) to let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=iferror(if(E264>G263,"",G263-E264),"")
```

You mentioned you want blank, possibly not zeroes, so the above should perform as needed, as opposed to the formula I gave in my comment.

You check if the relative value in E is greater than the relative value in G, which would lead to a engative result, and where true (vlaue would be negative) it displays "", otherwise it performs the subtraction.

The if-error is added due to comparing a number to a non-number, which may or may not flag (blank *should* be treated like 0, but we dont' want to be wrong).

Comment: Perfect! The IFERROR is what I needed, thanks so much!